# Create infinite list in Haskell of k-composite numbers

Tags: list, function, haskell

A k-composite number is a composite number with k factors excluding 1 and itself.  I'm trying to write code that will take in an integer k and return an infinite list of all k-composites. So using take 5 $ kcomposite 2 will return [6,8,10,14,15].  I wrote two functions to accomplish this:

```
factors :: Int -> [Int]
factors n = [x | x <- [1..n], n `mod` x == 0]

kcomposite ::  Int -> [Int]
kcomposite n = [x | x <- [1..], (length (factors n)) == (x-2)]
```

I have no trouble compiling, but when I try to run them, the ghci never stops running. This makes sense because of the infinite list, but this happens even when I only try to get the first few elements in the list, like in the above example.  I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like you switched x and n around. You need `(length (factors x)) == n-2`.

Comment: Also n+2 of course, not n-2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A k-composite number is a composite number with k factors excluding 1 and itself

Since your `factors` function returns all factors of a number (including `1` and itself), this number will be greater than the provided `k`. That's why you need to compare with `k + 2` instead of `k - 2`

Also, when `k` is less than `0` you'll still get the program never stop running, that's why you might want to process this edge case.

```
factors :: Int -> [Int]
factors n = [x | x <- [1..n], n `mod` x == 0]

kcomposite ::  Int -> [Int]
kcomposite k
  | k < 0 = []
  | otherwise = [x | x <- [1..], length (factors x) == (k + 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my slightly different approach for this task which is much more efficient.

The boosting key is to **not** check all the way to the end but only up to its **square root**. I mean if we want to find composites of 100 we don't need to control all 100 numbers. We only need to control up to `sqrt 100` (like `[2..10]`) to see `(mod 100 x) == 0`. We start from 2 since you don't want 1 and the number itself. Once we have the satisfying numbers `100 div x` should give us the other one. So if 2 is a composite then `100 div 2` (50) is another one like 4 yields 25 and 5 yields 20. Of course when we come to 10 it will give us another 10 and we will only evaluate one of them. Cool..!

So this is the code

```
kcomposites :: Int -> [Int]
kcomposites k = 
  let factors n = concat [bool [x, n `div` x] [x] (x^2 == n) 
                          | x <- [2..limit], n `mod` x == 0]
          where limit = truncate . sqrt . realToFrac $ n
  in foldr (\n rs -> bool rs (n:rs) (k == (length . factors $ n))) [] [2..]
```

Here is this code's performance for k = 19 for first 5 elements;

```
*Main> take 5 . kcomposites $ 19
[576,1600,2916,3136,7744]
(0.43 secs, 174,826,272 bytes)
```

and here is your code's performance for k = 19 for first 5 elements;

```
*Main> take 5 . kcomposite $ 19
[576,1600,2916,3136,7744]
(17.61 secs, 6,246,022,504 bytes)
```

Note: I wouldn't advice checking for k = 5 for 5 elements. Even this code took like 15 minutes to come up with `[64,729,15625,117649,1771561]` the above code will probably take a crazy amount of time (like a day or more perhaps).

Lets compare them with `take 3`.

```
*Main> take 3 . kcomposites $ 5
[64,729,15625]
(1.14 secs, 472,228,880 bytes)

*Main> take 3 . kcomposite $ 5
[64,729,15625]
(69.84 secs, 25,409,801,688 bytes)
```

Comment: ... and why 5? because 7 is prime, and so can only be got at through the n^6 numbers, i.e. those with just *one* prime factor.

Comment: @Will Ness Sorry... I am unsure what you mean... These 5 factors that we are after are not prime but largest ones.Numbers with 7 factors are plenty while finding a number with 9 factors seems to be even harder than finding one with 5. As a side note..  for a number to have odd numbers of factors it has to have a perfect integer square root.

Comment: if a number has *prime* factorization `p^a*q^b*r^c*...`, its total number of divisors is `product [a+1,b+1,c+1,...]`, including 1 and itself. So if it has 5 = 7-2 divisors excluding 1 and itself, it must be that `product [a+1,b+1,c+1,...] = 7`, but 7 is prime, so there can be only one entry in that list, `product [a+1] = (a+1) = 7` thus `a=6` and the prime factorization is `p^6` for some prime `p`. // for 7 factors, excluding, it is `product [a+1,b+1,c+1,...] = 9` for example `3*3 = 9` for a factorization of `p^2*q^2`, or also `p^8`. // 9 = 11-2, 11 is prime, factorization is `p^10`.

Comment: and naturally 10th powers are much more sparse than 6th powers.

Comment: @Will Ness Thank you for explanation. I've just got time to work out what exactly you mean. So finding numbers with `11, 15, 17, 21...  (p - 2)`  factors by this algorithm would be hard and wasteful.. Instead we better simply switch the logic to `take 5 . map (^(k+1)) $ primes` for such number of factors are required. Cool..!